# Sequence of closed intervals with a lenth less than $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: (Completeness Axiom): If $I_1,I_2,I_3,\dots$ is a sequence of closed intervals such that for each positive integer $n$, $I_{n+1}$ is a subset of $I_n$, and the length of $I_n$ is less than $\frac{1}{n}$, then there is only one one point $p$ such that for each positive integer $n, p$ is an element of $I_n$.

Proof:

Let $I_1,I_2,I_3,\dots$ be a sequence of closed intervals such that for each positive integer $n$, $I_{n+1}$ is a subset of $I_n$, and the length of $I_n$ is less than $\frac{1}{n}$

Our class' definition of the Completeness Axiom: If $M$ is a point set and there is a point to the right of every point of $M$, then there is either a right-most point of $M$ or a first point to the right of $M$. Similarly, if there is a point to the left of every point of $M$, then there is either a left-most point of $M$ or a first point to the left of $M$).

Let $M$ be the set $I_n$

Here is where I am confused, how would this help me solve this problem? I'm not sure where to go from here. I appreciate any help given. I apologize for how terrible this post is. I am new to this website.

Comment: I've added some mathjax to your post - [here's a quick guide for future reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Appreciate it Mehta.

Comment: What about assuming by contradiction that there are two such points, $p<q$, and choose $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{q-p}{2}$?

Comment: So by supposing there are two points that are in In and showing that it is not possible, will lead to a contradiction? I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there are two points $p<q$ such that $p,q\in\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}I_{n}$, then by Archimedean property, choose $n$ large enough such that $1/n<(q-p)/2$. Since $p,q\in I_{n}$, then the distance between $p$ and $q$ must less than the length of $I_{n}$, so $q-p<1/n$, so $q-p<(q-p)/2$, so $q-p<0$, so $q<p$, a contradiction.

Comment: Could explain what that giant upside "U" means?

Comment: It is the intersection of all such sets $I_{n}$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why you choose n such that it's (q-p)/2? We havn't went over the Archimedean property?

Comment: Then you have to use some imagination, when $n$ is very large, then $1/n$ is very small, since $(q-p)/2$ is a fixed positive number, we then let $1/n$ be very small, smaller than it.